# One type argument expected for interface Function <out R>

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, generics, jjwt

I am following a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X80nJ5T7YpE) to implement JWT authentication with spring boot and java. But in my case I want to do it with Kotlin.

I am able to generate a jwt token but having issues when extracting claims from a jwt token.

In this tutorial there is a generic function to extract claims from a token.

```
public <T> T extractClaim(String token, Function<Claims, T> claimsResolver {
    final Claims claims = extractAllClaims(token);
    return claimResolver.apply(claims);
}

private Claims extractAllClaims(String token) {
    return Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(KEY).parseClaimsJws(token).getBody();
}

public String extractUsername(String token) {
    return extractClaim(token, Claims::getSubject);
}
```

I have written this in kotlin as follows.

```
fun <T> extractClaim(token: String, claimResolver: Function<Claims, T>): T {
    val claims = extractAllClaims(token)
    return claimResolver.apply(claims)
}

private fun extractAllClaims(token: String): Claims {
    return Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(key).parseClaimsJws(token).body
}

fun extractUsername(token: String): String {
    return extractClaim(token, Claims::getSubject)
}
```

I'm getting an error from **Function<Claims, T>** saying

> One type argument expected for interface Function

Also I can see there are other options such as **KFunction** and **KFunction1**.

I am not much experienced in Kotlin and can someone help me to figure out the issue here or suggest a better way of doing this.

Comment: Are you importing the right `Function` class?

Comment: @gidds you are correct. I was importing wrong class. Now I changed it to java.util.function.Function. But Now I get Required Function<Claims, TypeVariable<T>> but Found KFunction1<Claims, String!> from extractUsername method Claims::getSubject

Answer (score 2):

Function types are some different in Kotlin, try with this:

```
fun <T> extractClaim(token: String, claimsResolver: (Claims) -> T): T {
    val claims: Claims = extractAllClaims(token)
    return claimsResolver(claims)
}
```